# Advanced Django Template Logic

Tags: django, templates, django-templates, boolean, logic

I'm not sure if this is really easy and I just glanced over it in the documentation, or if this is a limitation of the Django template system, but I need to be able to do a little (not very) advanced logic in Django, and I'd rather not have to repeat myself all over.

Let's say I have 3 boolean values; A, B, and C.

I basically need to do:

```
{% if A and (B or C) %}
    {{ do stuff }}
{% endif %}
```

However Django doesn't seem to allow grouping the `(B or C)` logic with parentheses. Is there a way to do that kind of grouping in Django's template language? Or do I need to do the un-DRY version of that, which would be:

```
  {% if A and B %}
        {{ do stuff }}
  {% else %}
      {% if A and C %}
          {{ do the same stuff }}
      {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The [docs for the if template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#if) say:

> Use of actual parentheses in the if tag is invalid syntax. If you need them to indicate precedence, you should use nested if tags.

This is a cleaner way to express your logic with nested tags:

```
{% if A %}
  {% if B or C %}
    {{ do stuff }}
  {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Ah. I see. That is considerably cleaner than what I had written, and even if it's not as simple as being able to use parentheses, at least it's fairly DRY. Thanks!

Comment: How would you add an `else` branch without duplicating it?

Comment: @JoachimBreitner - one way would be to negate the conditional, using the identities `~(A & B) == ~A | ~B` and `~(A | B) == ~A & ~B`. So `{% if not A or not B and not C %} else branch here {% else %}{{ do stuff }}{% endif %}`. That converts the expression into one where the non-parenthesized prioritization of the `not`, `and` and `or` operators gives the desired logic.

Comment: @djangodevs (re: @PeterDeGlopper's): tldr: you should allow parentheses, 'cause what Peter just explained is ridiculous to have to do

Comment: @JanKyuPeblik imo it's a good idea to push logic up from template to view or model code. Cleaner that way. I don't know, but would not be surprised, to find Django devs limiting template logic capability by design. e.g. for this problem:, in the view: context['do_my_stuff'] = A and (B or C), in template: {% if do_my_stuff %} ... {% endif %}

Comment: Except as you can see they haven't limited it, they've merely made it extremely annoying to do.

Answer (score 6):

Assign whatever inside the parenthesis to a variable.

```
{% with B or C as D %}
  {% if A and D %}
    {{ do stuff }}
  {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

PS: This does not work on newer versions.

Comment: @OlegTikhonov Not sure.  Not using Django nowadays.  However, I hope this must work as long as with and if tags exist.

Comment: No correct, django templating language only allows one value in a with statement, no logic whatsoever

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out @OlegTikhonov, observed that it doesn't work in newer versions.  Just tried on 1.11

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can 'expand' the contents of the parenthesis and evaluate it as:

```
{% if A and B or A and C %}
    {{ do stuff }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This can become messy, because of precedence that and has over or statement and it can lead to undesired results.

Comment: @BrankoRadojevic True, if the logic is complex it may be better to check in in the view and not make the template logic messy.