# Django template priority operator

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a condition

```
{% if AAA or BBB and CCC %} do something {% endif %}
```

Is it possible to do the OR first ?
I try

```
{% if (AAA or BBB) and CCC %} do something {% endif %}
```

But it doesn't work

```
Could not parse some characters: (
```

Comment: You can not use parenthesis in the Django template language.

Comment: How can I do otherwise ?

Comment: `{% if CCC or (AAA or BBB) %}`? Given `AAA`, `BBB` and `CCC` have no side-effects, the two are semantically equivalent.

Comment: I don't think because if CCC = False and AAA  = True then you have True as result ?

Comment: typo: `{% if CCC and (AAA or BBB) %}`

Comment: you can't have parenthesis ?

Comment: if AAA and CCC or  BBB and CCC works

Comment: Does this solve your problem ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/72997715/8237838

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Advanced Django Template Logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17866859/advanced-django-template-logic)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use parentheses in Django template if tests. However, you can nest `{% if %}`, so this is equivalent:

```
{% if AAA or BBB %} {% if CCC %} do something {%endif%} {%endif%}
```

also you can avoid nesting using `and` priority  higher than `or` as per MichaelS comment on question.